# API - How to get Product or Category by url/path?

Tags: magento2, angularjs

I'm working on an Angular 2 App in front of Magento2 and I would like to get URL Info to know where to go in my App and what to load.
We already have many Angular 1 Apps working like that with Drupal (in API mode), I would like to do the same with Magento 2 API.

Thank you for any answer/feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title of the question, I think I can help. I am trying to solve the same problem where I need to locate a category based on its URL path and was able to build a query that matches a category based on the nested URL path, rather than just the URL key. For my use case, I'm using an AJAX request to send the current URL path of the page to a controller that performs the query and returns the information about the category.

```
$urlKeys = ['some-parent', 'another-parent', 'final-category'];

// Select to resolve the URL path to the numeric path and category ID (we will validate later)
    $catgorySelect = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->select()
        ->from(['uk' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_url_key')])
        ->join(
            ['c' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog_category_entity')],
            'c.entity_id = uk.entity_id',
            ['c.path']
        )
        ->reset('columns')
        ->columns('c.entity_id')
        ->columns('uk.value')
        ->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr('@previous_path := c.path'))
        ->where('uk.value IN (?)', $urlKeys)
        ->where('uk.store_id IN (?)', [0, (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()])
        ->where('(c.parent_id = ? OR (@previous_path IS NOT NULL AND c.path LIKE CONCAT(@previous_path, "%")))', Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId())
        ->order('c.level ASC');

    $categories = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($catgorySelect);
    $lastCategory = array_pop($categories);

    // Reject if no matches with a valid entity ID or matching URL key
    if (empty($lastCategory) ||
        !array_key_exists('entity_id', $lastCategory) ||
        empty($lastCategory['entity_id']) ||
        !array_key_exists('value', $lastCategory) ||
        empty($lastCategory['value']) ||
        count($categories) !== count($urlKeys) || // Confirm we have the number of categories match the number of  URL segments
        $lastCategory['value'] !== array_pop($urlKeys) // Confirm the resulting category matches the last URL key
    ) {
        // Reject the category because no entity ID was found
    }
```

This query will take an array of URL segments (order is optional) and return the categories that have URL paths with the same keys. I've tested this with success on my own category hierarchy, but you should test this yourself to be certain.

**The 6th condition in the IF statement is important because the query will match technically invalid URL paths to a nested category.**

For example, a nested category has the URL path "*some-parent/another-parent/final-category*". If you were to provide "*some-parent*" and "*final-category*" as the only URL keys to match on in the query, it would still pull up the category for "*some-parent/another-parent/final-category*" despite not having the 2nd URL segment in the query. This could be seen as a bug or a benefit depending on how you want to handle fuzzy matching.